# Split a column into multiple columns in a SQL Server table but some invalid values are not aligned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need  to split a column into multiple columns in SQL Server 2012 (v11).

My data:

```
 a_value
----------------------------------------------------------
 (6, 5, 1908, 650)
 (16, 21, 3002, 110)
 (-228,117,29,335,279,700,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000)
 (-387,150,276,186,008)
 NULL
```

Most of the data has 3 commas (which are valid) but some of them are not. For these invalid values, I want to put them as a string in another column.

I want :

```
 w1    w2    w3    w4       w5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 6     5     1908  650      NULL 
 16   21     3002  110      NULL
 NULL NULL   NULL  NULL     (-228,117,29,335,279,700,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000)
 NULL NULL   NULL  NULL     (-387,150,276,186,008)
 NULL NULL   NULL  NULL     NULL
```

My SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN(a_value) >= 9 
          THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(substring(a_value, 1, LEN(a_value) -2), ',', '.'), 4)
          ELSE NULL
    END AS w1,
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN(a_value) >= 9 
          THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(substring(a_value, 1, LEN(a_value) -2), ',', '.'), 3)
          ELSE NULL
    END AS w2,
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN(a_value) >= 9 
          THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(substring(a_value, 1, LEN(a_value) -2), ',', '.'), 2)
          ELSE NULL
    END AS w3,
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN(window_pos_size) >= 9 
          THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(substring(a_value, 1, LEN(a_value) -2), ',', '.'), 1)
          ELSE NULL
    END AS w4
FROM 
    my_tbl
```

It does not work.

Any suggestions about the SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Just another option

**Example**

```
Select B.*
      ,W5 = case when W4 is null then a_value end
 From YourTable A
 Outer Apply (
    Select W1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(100)')))
          ,W2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')))
          ,W3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')))
          ,W4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(100)')))
     From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(replace(replace(a_value,'(',''),')',''),',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
     Where xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(100)') is null
 ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the logic that you want:

```
select (case when a_value not like '%,%,%,%,%'
             then PARSENAME(REPLACE(substring(a_value, 1, len(a_value) -2),',','.'),4)
        end) as w1,
       (case when a_value not like '%,%,%,%,%'
             then PARSENAME(REPLACE(substring(a_value, 1, len(a_value) -2),',','.'),3)
        end) as w2,
       (case when a_value not like '%,%,%,%,%'
             then PARSENAME(REPLACE(substring(a_value, 1, len(a_value) -2),',','.'),2)
        end) as w3,
       (case when a_value not like '%,%,%,%,%'
             then PARSENAME(REPLACE(substring(a_value, 1, len(a_value) -2),',','.'),1)
        end) as w4,
       (case when a_value like '%,%,%,%,%'
             then a_value
        end) as w5
```

This returns values for the fourth row, which your sample data does not.  You don't describe any filtering, so I assume this is correct.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=306210da01ac4ee1ffaeae7ec38c0356) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thanks, it should be '%,%,%,%' , 3 commas for valid rows ?

Comment: @user3448011 . . . I have included a db<>fiddle illustrating that the query works on the data you provided in the question.  The four commas are intentional, because the comparator is `not like`.

Comment: I made some changes to db<>fiddle, some rows may be blank. But the query does not work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is to count the commas:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   a_value varchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (a_value)
VALUES
   ('(6, 5, 1908, 650)'),
   ('(16, 21, 3002, 110)'),
   ('(-228,117,29,335,279,700,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000)'),
   ('(-387,150,276,186,008)'),
   (NULL)
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN(a_value) - LEN(REPLACE(a_value, ',', '')) = 3 
          THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(a_value, 2, LEN(a_value) -2), ',', '.'), 4)
          ELSE NULL
    END AS w1,
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN(a_value) - LEN(REPLACE(a_value, ',', '')) = 3 
          THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(a_value, 2, LEN(a_value) -2), ',', '.'), 3)
          ELSE NULL
    END AS w2,
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN(a_value) - LEN(REPLACE(a_value, ',', '')) = 3 
          THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(a_value, 2, LEN(a_value) -2), ',', '.'), 2)
          ELSE NULL
    END AS w3,
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN(a_value) - LEN(REPLACE(a_value, ',', '')) = 3 
          THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(a_value, 2, LEN(a_value) -2), ',', '.'), 1)
          ELSE NULL
    END AS w4,
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN(a_value) - LEN(REPLACE(a_value, ',', '')) = 3 
          THEN NULL
          ELSE a_value
    END AS w5
FROM 
    #Data
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
w1      w2      w3      w4      w5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
6       5       1908    650     NULL
16      21      3002    110     NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    (-228,117,29,335,279,700,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000)
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    (-387,150,276,186,008)
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```